# OleDbConnection opens sheet as read-only in any open Excel Window

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

This is pretty much exact question of :
[OleDbConnection() opens an Excel file in any open Excel window. But does not if there isnt a window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229929/oledbconnection-opens-an-excel-file-in-any-open-excel-window-but-does-not-if), but it had no answers.

If I have multiple Excel windows open, my program will open a read-only sheet in any Excel window. I.e. if I have Test.xlsx open, and a blank sheet in another window (let's say my program wants to write to Test.xlsx); when I do:

`OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);`

`myConn.Open();`

a read-only copy of Test.xlsx will open in the blank window, and the program will operate on that. Is there a way to ensure that `myConn` uses the already open Test.xlsx?

If it helps, my `conn` variable is:

"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\temp\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=No""

Comment: Do you need "Extended Properties" in the connection string? It's a very strange issue...

Comment: I removed the "Extended Properties" part and the same issue still arises.

Comment: If I open my Test.xlsx first and a blank window second, my program works. I assume this means the connection will act on the sheet that was most recently opened (as in take the first connection from a pool?).. maybe I just need a way to force it to use a certain connection

Comment: I guess an OLEDB connection shouldn't use Excel at all so I'm surprised it affects existing Excel instances even if the same file is in use...