# Excel OLE DB opens sheet in the background -- how to prevent that?

Tags: excel, oledb, ole

I'm in Excel 2010, using the "Data->From Other Sources" wizard to import data from another sheet. I'm opening the sheet read-only, and it imports data fine even if somebody else already has the sheet that I'm importing open. However, if someone else does already have that sheet open, then my import launches a new Readonly instance of my sheet in an excel window. Also, that other instance of excel stays around even after the data is imported. (That doesn't happen if the sheet isn't already open by somebody else -- in that case my data connection wizard just sucks in the data). How can I make it not open that sheet in  the background?

Here's my connection string -- note that it is read-only.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=H:\Departments\RMBS\REIT Model\Reit Portfolio 2013-6-28.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;ReadOnly=true";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

Very similar issue is here, but there's no answer:
[OleDbConnection opens sheet as read-only in any open Excel Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300827/oledbconnection-opens-sheet-as-read-only-in-any-open-excel-window)

Comment: The connection string looks wrong to me - compare it with the one at http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007 Specifically the "Excel 8.0" part in your connection string relates to Excel 2003 and earlier whereas the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" part relates to Excel 2007 and later

Comment: Yes, I tried EXCEL 8.0 and 12.0 -- I get the same behavior either way.